# Are these curves closed in the following domains?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

I have thought of two curves and I'm wondering if they are closed. $\gamma_1(t)=(\sin t,0,0)$ and $\gamma_2(t)=(t-\left \lfloor{t}\right \rfloor  ,0,0)$. Intuitively, I think they should both be closed, but I'm worried about issues of smoothness/domain. Does it make a difference if I consider the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$, $[0,2\pi)$, or $[0,2\pi)$?

Comment: of course the domain makes all the difference.

Comment: @ironX Would you be able to tell me if each curve is closed for the three possible domains?